# Where does Laravel Scout store Meilisearch settings?

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I don't mean filters, I mean settings: https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/api/settings.html

So let's say I wanted to change the default Meilisearch 'stopword' setting for a specific model (or even all models)

```
$client->index('movies')->updateStopWords(['the', 'of', 'to']);
```

how could I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Scout creates a singleton with the Meilisearch client. That means you can access the instance from anywhere within your laravel container like this :

```
$client = app(\MeiliSearch\Client::class);
$client->index('movies')->updateStopWords(['the', 'of', 'to']);
```

Comment: Are you supposed to have this code somewhere in your app or do you run it as a one-off through the console?

Comment: @neojp The settings are not saved anywhere, they are read at runtime which means it has to be in your app, in `ScoutServiceProvider` for example.